# How to detect motion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, video, motion

I am using this code for getting User media and putting in `<video>` using JavaScript now I want to check is there any movement happens or not.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  })
```

Comment: You will have to elaborate on what you mean by "movement"? ... Are you looking to do a security type application? If so, if it were built in functionality, you wouldn't be here.

Comment: actually it's for small babies, I developed one video/audio streaming web application that will constantly stream video on an android device and now I just want to add nofification when a baby will do any kind of movement.

Comment: `now I just want to add nofification  when a baby will do any kind of movement` sounds like the *hard* part.